# Minicom not working

Tags: raspbian, gpio, arduino, communication

I am trying to connect my Pi 4 running Rasbian 2020 to an Arduino, after making all the connections I try to communicate with the Arduino by using Minicom. However, Minicom doe not respond to anything I am typing nor any of the commands such as `ctrl + a`.

I am running Minicom with the following command:
`minicom -b 9600 -o -D /dev/ttyAMA0`

This is the code I have running on the Arduino:

```
byte number = 0;

void setup(){
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
if (Serial.available()) {
number = Serial.read();
Serial.print("character recieved: ");
Serial.println(number, DEC);
}
}
```

Comment: Have you uploaded some Serial code into your Arduino and set the bit rate ? `/dev/ttyAMA0` exists on your RPI ? `-o` is really necessary ?

Comment: Yh, I do. I just put that up. Also, yes the baud rates match.

Comment: From this [example](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/read/),  your condition `if (Serial.available()) {}` must be `if (Serial.available() > 0){} `, I check if it is important

Comment: [available](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/available/) -> Returns :The number of bytes available to read., For Arduino Mega the example code is the same as you.

Comment: Try to add `int bytesSent = Serial.write("hello");` in your loop before `if (Serial.available()) {}` to see if you see anything in minicom ?

Comment: I haven't used minicom for a while but I can read: `it's <CTRL>+<A>, then <Z>`, you can also use `screen` instead of `minicom`

Comment: `<CTRL>+<A>` is supposed to set you into special inputs so you can use the keys for a plethora of commands... not just the `z`. The `<CTRL>+<A>` command is not doing that for me.

Also the `Serial.write` did nothing.

Comment: ok sorry i don't remember well how to use minicom.

Comment: maybe try with `screen` ? [help](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/terminal-basics/command-line-windows-mac-linux)

Comment: No luck. I tried `screen /dev/ttyAMA0 9600`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134647/discussion-between-ephemeral-and-beulah-akindele).

Answer (score 2):

`/dev/ttyAMA0` is connected to Bluetooth so this won't work.

See [How do I make serial work on the Raspberry Pi3 or later](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/45571/8697)

It IS POSSIBLE to disable Bluetooth but this is unnecessary to use serial. In the unlikely event you really need a fully featured UART the Pi4 has another 4.

There is no such thing as "Rasbian 2020"

Comment: Why do you think it is unnecessary to use Serial? and What do you mean by fully-featured UART?

Comment: @BeulahAkindele "Why do you think it is unnecessary to use Serial" is said no such thing - re read the Answer.

Comment: @BeulahAkindele "What do you mean by fully-featured UART" the linked Answer explains the difference between mini UART & fully-featured UART.